# Proving two functions are equivalent given equal integrals without fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration

I want to prove that given two functions $f$ and $g$ that are continuous on the interval $[a,b]$, $\int_a^x f(t) \, dt=\int_a^x g(t) \, dt \; \forall x \in [a,b]$ implies that $f=g$ on the interval without using the fundamental theorem of calculus or Lebesgue integration. The conclusion seems relatively intuitive, but I don't think claiming intuition and "matching integrands" is rigorous enough. I initially tried to use Cauchy sums to prove this result, but I got stuck after realizing that Cauchy sums are primarily used to prove that functions are Riemann integrable, whereas in this question, we want to prove that the two functions $f$ and $g$ are equivalent. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\int_c^{d} f(x)dx=\int_c^{d} g(x)dx$ if $a \leq c <d \leq b$. Suppose $f(s) >g(s)$ for some $s$. Let $r=f(s)-g(s)$. Then, by continuity,  we can find an interval $(c,d)$ such that $f(t)>g(t)+\frac  r 2$ for all $t$ in $(c,d)$. This implies that $\int_c^{d} f(x)dx> \int_c^{d} g(x)dx +\frac {r(d-c)} 2$, a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make the steps concrete, how did you conclude that $f(t)>g(t)+\frac{r}{2} \; \forall t \in [c,d] \Rightarrow \int_c^d f(x) \, dx > \int_c^d g(x) \, dx + \frac{r}{2}$? Is it not true that the inequality only implies $\int_c^d f(x) \, dx > \int_c^d g(x) \, dx + \frac{r(d-c)}{2}$? Obviously the conclusion is the same, but I just wanted to make sure that I'm understanding the proof correctly.

Comment: @jaymathy You are right. I made  a mistake. I have corrected it.